# vectorized matrix power and matrix dot using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I want to calculate the power of many 2-D matrices, and would like to do it as fast as possible. I couldn't find a vectorized method to do it.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
mat_list = [np.mat(np.random.randn(100,100)) for i in range(1000)]
output = [np.linalg.matrix_power(mat_list[i], 100) for i in xrange(len(mat_list))]
```

I would like to the same for dot multiplications:

```
import numpy as np
mat_list1 = [np.mat(np.random.randn(100,100)) for i in range(1000)]
mat_list2 = [np.mat(np.random.randn(100,100)) for i in range(1000)]
output = [np.dot(a,b) for a,b in zip(mat_list1,mat_list2)]
```

Comment: I doubt that, in the scheme of things, having the outer loop written in Python is that much of a performance drag.

Comment: `np.einsum('ijk,ikl->ijl',mat_list1,mat_list2)` is a vectorized `dot`, but with these relative dimensions, it does not save time.  With fewer, but larger matricies it might be faster.

Comment: Agree with @NPE - the outer loops are relatively minimal. You could profile your code to see how insignificant it is. But fwiw, your first `output` doesn't need an iteration variable - just do `output = [np.linalg.matrix_power(m, 100) for m in mat_list]`.